# get dimension of an svg including stroke

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I want to place an svg precisely into the corner of a div. The svg has a dynamic generated stroke. If the shape of the svg is irregular or lets say a star, the distance to the outmost part of the border is hard to calculate.
The problem could be solved, if I would be able to get the dimensions of the svg including the stroke.

My idea is:

- load the external svg
- place it in the middle of the div
- apply the desired stroke-width
- get the outmost dimensions of the svg
- place it in the corner

Can I get the width of the svg including the stroke? Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) is the only way short of calculating it yourself from first principles. That method is only implemented in Firefox and IE9+ as far as I know though.

For example [this](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/HxYjg/) returns 54 on Firefox.

Comment: I tried this in firefox but I got the dimensions of the shape without the stroke :-(

Comment: I've added an example showing that stroke-width is included at least on Firefox.

Comment: Just noting that http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#the-getclientrects-and-getboundingclientrect-methods says that the boundingbox for svg elements should be the one defined in svg (which currently does not include the stroke).

Comment: Which I reported as a bug in the specification: http://old.nabble.com/Re%3A--cssom-view--6.1-getBoundingClientRect-with-SVG-content-p32193453.html

Comment: So there is no cross-browser-solution for the moment?

Comment: No, the SVG specification does not currently let you do this. I think the next version of the specification proposes a way to do it though.